# Maximum reputation you can earn from editing answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

I was talking a friend and we recently just really got into stackoverflow and we were wondering if there is a maximum reputation you can earn from editing questions per day. IF there is, what is it?

For example: If I am editing 200 questions a day and that will probably make me 400 points so my questions is: is there a limit to how many questions I can edit? and how many points I can get from editing questions per day?

Comment: Since neither of the answers so far mention this point - it probably goes without saying, but please, don't edit a ton of questions ***just*** to rack up the maximum rep per day. Edit questions because they need to be improved, don't just find 200 (or even 100) things you "could" edit because it'll get you points.

Comment: I am not looking for points. I was wondering. There is no point in racking up points and be proud of it when it is just edits you used to get it. So yeah I'd rather not waste my time just editing questions to rack points

Comment: I didn't figure you were - but in a place where a question will stand forever for future readers to come across, it's better safe than sorry to put common sense stuff like that in writing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit of 200 rep / day, including from suggested edits and upvotes, and excluding from accepts & bounties.

There is no limit to how much you can edit, as long as your edits are approved, and you can earn a maximum of 1000 rep total from suggested edits.

After you reach 2k rep, edits are no longer rewarded with reputation, but they are applied immediately, and you can also review edits by others.

Also, until you reach 20k rep, tag wiki and excerpt edits will still give you 2 rep each, and are reviewed.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you get a maximum of 1,000 reputation from editing, with a limit of 200 per day.